# remove reflection of light but keep surface reflective

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, reflection

I have a material in my scene that is reflective and it seems to be reflecting the source of the area light. I tried to find the ray visibility options but I'm using eevee so they aren't there. how can I fix this?

EDIT: I should probably mention I want to keep the roughness value of the material at 0 and I cant share the blend file because it contains many paid assets and its well over 100mb

[image: light reflections]

Comment: In the light setting, try changing the Specular to 0.0

Comment: In the angle setting try narrowing to something that would not include the undesired area.

Comment: changing the specular of the light to 0 worked